# html5 jquery - Multiple buttons feed different values into field in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm currently trying to work out how to use jQuery to use multiple buttons to feed different values into a field in a form that is located in a shared modal.

At the moment I have three buttons labelled "Add Notes", "Add Visit" and "Make Call", each triggering the same modal, like below for example:

```
<button id="AddVisitButton" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddNotesModal">
      <i class="fa fa-car"></i>&nbsp; Add Visit
</button>

<button id="MakeCallButton" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddNotesModal">
      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp; Make Call
</button>
```

The plan is to have each button which, when clicked, will feed a number into the Category field in the modal (a number that is tied to a specific CategoryID on a SQL database) which is currently called using recordsets in a Select dropdown:

```
<select name="Category" required class="form-control" id="Category">
    <option value="">Select...</option>

    <option value="<%=(rsNtsC.Fields.Item("NotesCategoryID").Value)%>">
    <%=(rsNtsC.Fields.Item("NotesCategory").Value)%> 
    </option>

</select>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas, as having multiple modals is very costly in speed and rather untidy, especially when they all do the same function but just apply a different category of note.

Many thanks.

EDIT: I must also confirm that I am stuck using Classic ASP for this system.

EDIT 2: From what I have worked out on my own, I need whatever jQuery spits out to go into this section:

```
<option value="**<%=(rsNtsC.Fields.Item("NotesCategoryID").Value)%>**">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this was not solved and we went with a different method that triggers through the button sending a value then hiding the category all together.